# Trace 32 How to retrieve user input asynchronously

Tags: debugging, asynchronous, embedded, trace32, lauterbach

I'm running a script and whenever a breakpoint is hit, a subroutine will be executed, printing/retrieving a buffer's information, asynchronously.

This process will be performed for an indefinite time, until a user wants to stop this process.

Is there a way to present the user with a dialog/message asking him to signal when the script finishes. And if the user clicks on the "Finish execution" button, the script execution ends.

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Not sure if dialogues are possible but you can add a custom icon/button to the debugger toolbar, that in turn triggers a script. Perhaps that would be acceptable?